# Há problemas de segurança ao utilizar sessionStorage para armazenamento de dados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, segurança

Existe algum problema relacionado com segurança de um sistema web que utilize `sessionStorage` para armazenamento de dados temporários de um usuário? Na prática, o uso de [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) é uma boa prática?

Em minha aplicação, ao invés de sempre realizar uma requisição ao banco de dados para aquisição de uma informação, carrego vários dados pertinentes uma vez e as guardo em uma `sessionStorage` para poder manipular em diversas áreas da aplicação. Essa prática implica em possíveis problemas de segurança da aplicação em geral?

Comment: Veja esse post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36958/is-it-safe-to-store-password-in-html5-sessionstorage

Comment: Duds, em vez de esclarecer nos comentários, por favor, edite a pergunta para adicionar essa informação, depois é só avisar quem te perguntou "@renan, pergunta editada"

Comment: Tudo que fica do lado do cliente é editável além da intenção original da aplicação. Segurança é muito relativo, depende onde usa os dados, e qual a importância deles. Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e colocar num contexto mais prático, me parece muito ampla a questão da forma que está.

Comment: Não é uma resposta para a sua pergunta, mas é um toque para algo que você pode não ter pensado: você está usando o sessionStorage como uma camada de cache para armazenar dados que vai usar depois, assim evitando fazer requests extras no server para buscar eles, o que é interessante já que aumenta a velocidade do app e diminui a carga no servidor, contudo você pode cair em problemas de invalidação de cache. Pense assim: você guardou algo como o endereço do user na sessionStorage, depios o user atualizou isso no server, e agora seu sessionStorage está com dados desatualizados/inválidos.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues já que é sameOrigin você sabe se ao utilizar algum js pelo console do browser, é possível pegar os dados da sessionStorage?

Comment: @Duds, procure sempre criptografar os dados importantes, como tokens de sessão e outros, assim só você tem a key. Outra questão que vi é que você diz que pode manipular esses dados mais facilmente, veja que se dois usuários tem os mesmos dados e um ao atualizar o outro pode não receber o update, e este que não recebeu o update pode atualizar querer atualizar novamente um conteúdo que já estava atualizado,ou seja, se for assim você deve criar uma rotina de verificação, se forem dados compartilhados não é bom fazer o uso de sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

A minha resposta é sim e não. Depende do tipo de dados que você está guardando na sessão.

Basta ter em conta que esses são dados que o utilizador pode ver se abrir a consola do navegador. Devemos sempre assumir que alguém vai fazer isso.

**Sim**.

Se você estiver guardando chaves como nome e password de utilizadores do seu site. Ou outras informações sensíveis. 
Se você estiver dependendo de um determinado valor, tenha em conta que o utilizador pode alterar esse valor e originar falhas no seu site.

**Não**.

Se estiver a usar a sessão para coisas simples e que não comprometam o funcionamento do seu site se o seu valor for alterado.